# How to use Symfony EntityType with only add option?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would like to have a EntityType form field for manyToMany relationship (expanded=true, multiple=true) which gives a possibility to only add new relationships but not remove already added.

I could be either:

- a field with checkboxes to check to add a new relationships to entity
  or
- the full list of entities (already added and new ones that can by assigned by checking checkboxes) where those already added are disabled, so that user cannot uncheck them

How to achieve this?

In both cases those disabled or those that are not in the form field are removed from relationship.

Comment: You should use CollectionType instead of EntityType you have option to disable delete, i think the doc will help you https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: But I don't want to create a new Entity. I want to add only a manyToMany relationships between entity A and some of entities B. I don't want to create a new B entity. CollectionType would create a new one, right?

Comment: why not use query_builder inside the formType and you select  only the list that not already added , you can use "where not member of entity.relation)

Comment: @hous I have already done it this way but those entities B that are already assigned to entity A, and are not shown in the form (due to queryBuilder) are removed from the mamyToMany table after saving the form. If Doctrine doesn't see entities B within data from submited form, it removes them. I don't know how to change this behaviour.